# Which statistical methods are better than basic random scans for studying and exploring the parameter space of extensions of the standard model?

Tags: probability, statistics, beyond-the-standard-model

Given a lagrangian of a new model beyond the standard model, and given a set of constraints, say the oblique parameters for instance and the decay of the higgs boson and some signal strengths and branching ratios, up till now with my professor we have been using the random number generator ran2 (from numerical recipes) to scan the ranges of the free parameters and see if the calculated quantities are allowed by the constraints.
However, looking over the literature, I find that most people use fancier methods such as likeihood functions and monte carlo. But the details of their caculations and implementations are far from explicit and seem arbitrary (especially the choice of the probability distribution to sample from).

My question is: are these methods justified for this kind of phenomenological studies ? If so, on what basis do we choose the probability distribution ? Is there any link between the likelihood function and the lagrangian of the model ?

Any suggestions of books/papers that clarify these topics are also much appreciated.